# Xcode 7.2.1: Library build is not build 'lHexColor'

Tags: ios, xcode, build

Xcode Library link is not working...

Build problem:

```
Ld /Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios.Bynd-dsufpmwjucukmkctjyybhovuitqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ios.Bynd.app/ios.Bynd normal arm64
    cd /Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios.Bynd-dsufpmwjucukmkctjyybhovuitqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios.Bynd-dsufpmwjucukmkctjyybhovuitqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd/Pods/TwitterCore/iOS -F/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd/ios.Bynd/parse -F/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd -F/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios.Bynd-dsufpmwjucukmkctjyybhovuitqt/Build/Intermediates/ios.Bynd.build/Debug-iphoneos/ios.Bynd.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ios.Bynd.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.1 -dead_strip -ObjC -lHexColors -lMixpanel -lPDTSimpleCalendar -lTSMessages -lc++ -licucore -lz -framework Accelerate -framework Accounts -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreTelephony -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework TwitterCore -framework UIKit -ObjC -framework Accelerate -ObjC -lHexColors -lMixpanel -lPDTSimpleCalendar -lTSMessages -lc++ -licucore -lz -framework Accelerate -framework Accounts -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreTelephony -framework Crashlytics -framework Fabric -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework Social -framework SystemConfiguration -framework TwitterCore -framework UIKit /Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework QuartzCore -framework Foundation -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreGraphics -lHexColors -framework Accelerate -framework Bolts -framework Social -framework Accounts -lstdc++.6 -framework StoreKit -framework Parse -framework Security -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CFNetwork -framework MapKit -lsqlite3 -lz -framework CoreLocation -framework ParseCrashReporting -framework AudioToolbox -framework Parse -framework ParseCrashReporting -framework ParseUI -lPods-ios.Bynd -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios.Bynd-dsufpmwjucukmkctjyybhovuitqt/Build/Intermediates/ios.Bynd.build/Debug-iphoneos/ios.Bynd.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ios.Bynd_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios.Bynd-dsufpmwjucukmkctjyybhovuitqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ios.Bynd.app/ios.Bynd

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/abraaobarroslacerda/Documents/Urbbox/bynd/workspace/ios.Bynd/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lHexColors
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My PodFile:

```
target 'ios.Bynd' do
    pod 'PDTSimpleCalendar', '~> 0.9.1'
    pod 'Mixpanel'
    pod 'TSMessages'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'TwitterCore'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
end

target 'ios.ByndTests' do

    pod 'Parse'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'

end
```

Someone can give advisers how to dix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to go in the build settings of your project, look for other linker flags and remove every entries with -l"pod name". They are old CocoaPods entries.